# Бот в Дискорде команды и события

Tags: python, discord.py

Вот мой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'ODMzMzA1NzIwNDM0ODUxODkw.YHwabQ.yjsqDSgUaLq91qytDq6Wz8t440w'


hello_words = ['привет', 'здравствуй', 'Добрый день', 'Добрый вечер', 'Доброе утро']
info_words = ["как сделать", "куда обратиться", "помощь", "помогите", "поддержка"]
bye_words = ["пока", "прощай", "досвидания", "до свидания"]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Я готов {0.user}".format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    msg = message.content.lower()

    find_hello_words = False
    for item in hello_words:
        if msg.find(item) >= 0:
            find_hello_words = True

    if find_hello_words:
        await message.channel.send("Здравствуйте, чего изволите?")

    find_info_words = False
    for item in info_words:
        if msg.find(item) >= 0:
            find_info_words = True

    if find_info_words:
        await message.channel.send("Спасибо за обращение, ожидайте, вам скоро ответит админ!")

    find_bye_words = False
    for item in bye_words:
        if msg.find(item) >= 0:
            find_bye_words = True

    if find_bye_words:
        await message.channel.send("Было приятно пообщаться! До встречи!")


@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    print("старт")
    await ctx.message.channel.send("Поехали!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Почему-то когда запускаю, и пишу например "!hi", то выводит "Поехали!", а когда пытаюсь после этого, не выключая бота, написать например "Пока", он не овтечает, и реагирует только на "!hi"
Если пробую первым делом написать например "Привет", он мне нормально отвечает, но уже не реагирует на команду "!hi".
Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы создали две переменные - `bot` и `client`. Так бот работать не будет, уберите `client = discord.Client()` и `client.run(TOKEN)`, а в остальных местах замените везде `client` на `bot`.
2. Добавьте `await bot.process_commands(message)` в `on_message`.